# GPS Strategy over several Activites

Tags: android, gps, location, locationmanager, locationlistener

I have a question about the GPS Strategy, if I use GPS in several Activities.

Links, I searched trough:
[Location Strategies Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html)[Location Listener Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html)[Location Manager Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)

For Example: I have three Activities (A,B,C) in my Application. In each of these Activities I start to listen to the GPS Signal in the onResume Method. In each of these Activities I stop to listen to the GPS Signal in the onPause Method.
I do this, to avoid listening if another Application comes to the front (Activity X).

For a better understanding of my Problem I have a Picture:
[image: model]

Question 1: is this way correct, or is there a better way?

Question 2: If the user switches fast trough my activities, whats about the perfomance if I allways register and unregister the LocationListener?

Thanks for help!
Lukas

Answer (score 0):

You can try moving all your code into a service and getting status from there. 
It's also best to have a separate class that you manage for Gelocation , let's say a Geolocation manager and use it in your activities.

That way you ca do better tracking in your app.

Take a look at MyTracks ;) https://code.google.com/p/mytracks/source/browse/#hg%2FMyTracks%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fandroid%2Fapps%2Fmytracks%2Fservices